# How to remove duplicates of inner query that was used to remove duplicates in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a SQL Server question, so here are the tables I am working with (note: column `NAME` is the name of the code set):

Table: **CODE SET**

```
CODE_SET_ID  | NAME
-------------+-----------
1            | JACKETS
2            | PANTS
3            | SHIRTS
```

Table: **CODE SET DETAIL**

```
CODE           | DESCRIPTION    | CODE_SET_ID
---------------+----------------+------------
BLUE           | BLUE JACKET    | 1
BLUE           | BLUE JACKET    | 1
GREEN          | GREEN JACKET   | 1
GREEN          | GREEN JACKET   | 1
PURPLE         | PURPLE JACKET  | 1
```

The query I wrote currently finds all duplicate code set codes and which code set those code set codes belong too. The following query would return

```
JACKETS, BLUE,  2
JACKETS, GREEN, 2
```

How would I wrap another query around the following query so that I only get `JACKETS`?

```
SELECT 
    bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE, bcsd.DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    CODE_SET_DETAIL as bcsd
INNER JOIN 
    CODE_SET as bcs ON bcsd.CODE_SET_ID = bcs.CODE_SET_ID
GROUP BY 
    bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE, bcsd.DESCRIPTION
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

So far, I've tried using `WHERE EXISTS`, yet the result set does not look correct.

Comment: Why does your table sample not match your SQL in column names or your output match the query?

Comment: Put `WHERE bcs.NAME = 'JACKET'` before `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH X (Name, Code, Description, DetailCount) AS (
    SELECT bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE, bcsd.DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*)
    FROM CODE_SET_DETAIL as bcsd
    INNER JOIN CODE_SET as bcs 
    ON bcsd.CODE_SET_ID = bcs.CODE_SET_ID
    GROUP BY bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE, bcsd.DESCRIPTION
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM X
```

Comment: In order to make this query work, I had to provide an alias for the `COUNT(*)` column and I had to add an alias for the sub query result set.

Comment: Updated query to handle MS SQL requirements without changing original query.

Comment: I ended up with the following query thanks to @NetMage
`SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM (
    SELECT bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM B_CODE_SET_DETAIL as bcsd
    INNER JOIN B_CODE_SET as bcs 
    ON bcsd.CODE_SET_ID = bcs.CODE_SET_ID
    GROUP BY bcs.NAME, bcsd.CODE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as subQuery`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want only the "jackets" value, why don't you add " bcs.name='jackets' " to your HAVING clause and skip the whole outer query, or am I missing something?

Comment: What if he had PANTS and SHIRTS as well?